# Can players tap lands for mana with Enchanted Evening and Grand Abolisher in play?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I play [Enchanted Evening](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=151979) and turn everything into an enchantment, and then play [Grand Abolisher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=221898) to disallow them activating abilities during my turn, can my opponents tap their lands during my turn (say, to make a payment for something)?

Comment: Just wondering: are you going to use this interaction to pull some kind of hilarious trick? Because, if you are, I want to know what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they cannot.

From the rulings on Enchanted Evening:

> This has no effect on those permanents other than letting them interact with things that care about enchantments.

Which Grand Abolisher clearly interacts with:

> During your turn, your opponents can't cast spells or activate abilities of artifacts, creatures, or ***enchantments***.

I think it's clear that lands have an innate implied ability, even if not printed of "Tap: Add 1 mana of the appropriate colour to your mana pool."

So all we need to know is that this ability is treated like any other:

> CR 605.3. Activating an activated mana ability follows the rules for activating any other activated ability (see rule 602.2)

The exceptions listed don't apply to this case because Grand Abolisher is not countering the mana ability, it is preventing it from happening.  Just because it's a mana ability doesn't make it special in this case.

Comment: I thought there was a weird exception for mana abilities, but I'm not sure; hence why I asked the question here

Comment: @DForck42 Hopefully my edits help clear that up.

Comment: DForck42: I think you're thinking of the longago (pre-6th edition) rules about Mana Abilities, which said that they couldn't be countered; IIRC this briefly covered even spells like Dark Ritual.  Those changes are long-since gone, and now things that don't affect mana abilities explicitly say so, but effects like Null Rod's (or Grand Abolisher's, or Linvala's) aren't at all picky.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki 605.3b An activated mana ability doesn’t go on the stack, so it can’t be targeted, countered, or
otherwise responded to. Rather, it resolves immediately after it is activated.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Grand Abolisher is preventing activating the activated mana ability per 605.3 but if the ability were activated, it could not be countered per 605.3b

Comment: @Stephen D'oh - yes, absolutely you're right here.  I need to get back into the habit of scanning the comp rules again before making proclamations.  Mea culpa. :/  (A big part of the reason that mana abilities don't go on the stack is because they can be played while paying costs for a spell, yes?)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Presumably ... I would even say costs in general (can you prevent a sacrifice to pay costs?  I don't think so but you might be able to prevent an activation before a sacrifice), but it's well beyond my expertise to speculate on design decisions :-)

Comment: Back then mana sources and counterspells were interrupt speed rather than instant speed though. I suppose in a way mana sources still are interrupt speed, just nothing else is so they appear to happen immediately!

Comment: @AlexP Since it can't be done, whatever the original poster's goal was can't be achieved ... it was clever, just against the rules :)

Comment: @Stephen Well, no, the trick would be to *prevent* them from getting mana and then use that to your advantage (e.g. some weird tax effect?); I don't know why I made my comment a comment on the answer and not the question, though -- oops.